# Oracle UPDATE statement performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

The question is, which of the two is more performant in case of many (>1000) ids and why?

1) This one executed one by one for each id, and commit only after the last:

```
UPDATE User u SET u.status='ACTIVE' WHERE u.id=1;
```

2) Or:

```
UPDATE User u SET u.status='ACTIVE' WHERE u.id IN (1,2,3....)
```

Comment: A single update will be more efficient than row-by-row, but `in()` can only take 1000 values. Where are the IDs to be updated coming from? If you're deciding which to update based on other data in the DB then there a direct correlated update would be better.

Comment: More efficient approach would be, dumps these ids in a temporary table and then update using exists.

Comment: It would be executed by a Java-program through Hibernate, so I have to make it sure that it does not generate the first variant, but the second one to be more performant. (most probably CriteriaUpdate)

Comment: @clementino . . . Off-hand, I cannot think of a scenario where I would expect the first method to have better performance.  In general, it is better to do database operations in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that the second case should outperform the first.  By how much depends on how you are running these update statements.  If you plan to run them from a client, e.g. a Java program, then your first approach would incur a big latency penalty, as you keep opening new database connections for each update.  If just running separate updates on Oracle directly, you might not see much difference in performance if the list of id's in the second case are reasonably small.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It would be executed by a Java-program through Hibernate, so I will have to formulate the update queries to end up in the second variant.

Comment: @clementino Yes, definitely, you should do that.  _Unless_ your business logic is that these records would be getting updated separately, one at a time, in which case you don't have any choice.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between those two statements, and the optimiser will transform the `IN` to the `=` for each ID. 
But You can always check it by Execution Plans.
[Generating and Displaying Execution Plans](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL271)

Comment: The optimiser will not transform a single update with an `in()` to multiple individual updates. Maybe you're confusing it with seeing `in()` transformed to multiple `or` conditions? That's still a single statement though...

Comment: You're right. I should expand my answer.
`WHERE u.id IN (1,2,3)` is the same as
`WHERE u.id=1 or u.id=2 or u.id=3`, and I'm talking about `=` in this kind of  statement.

Comment: But that isn't what the OP's first version is doing; that has 1000+ separate update statements. So they are not the same at all, and that transformation isn't really relevant to this question.